# Loading and using a codeigniter model from another model

Tags: codeigniter, model

Fellow coders, using codeigniter 1.7.3 can I load a model from the code of another model? I have read many posts theoretical and practical but none gave a final answer.

I have a model that has a function in which i would like to perform an operation on another model. the code is like this:

```
1: $this->load->model('decision_model');
2: $this->decision_model->hello_decision();
```

line 1 works. line 2 fails as follows:

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined property: Account_model::$decision_model
Filename: models/account_model.php

I have tried creating simple dumb models, changed function names, giving the model an alias when loading it, etc... no luck

So, theory aside, is this doable?

thanks in advance.

Comment: usually you want to do that when a model references another model (e.g. using a foreign key in RDBM). In which case the original model will have a `decision_model` attribute that refers to the linked model. If you don't have such, then the models aren't linked and using `$this->load` from your first model will not link the loaded model to anything useful.

Comment: Already answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/872623/accessing-codeigniter-models-in-other-models

Comment: You may wish to look at the Kohana framework which is based on CI but allows things like this.

Comment: I've already read that thread and it gives two conflicting answers: Phil says the code i would like to use is possible in CI whereas the others are offering workarounds. So, which one is the correct answer and why is my code failing? thanks

Comment: @Guss, the two model are supposed to be linked - that's why i'm trying to access the second model. If i have reference (i'm assuming you are referring to a class attribute) in the original model, how would I initialize it to refer to the Decision model? thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
class User_model extends Model
{
    function get_something()
    {
         $CI =& get_instance();
         $CI->load->model('profile_model');
         return $CI->profile_model->get_another_thing();
    }
}
```

Comment: that did it! thanks so much :) i was doing something similar but moving the code into a helper and all that. it was getting pretty ugly. thanks again.

Comment: In CI 2.0 you can just call one model directly from another.

Comment: @phirschybar +1 I would have used `get_instance` if it wasn't for your comment (CI 2.1).. :)

Answer (score 10):

In CI 2.0 you can just call one model directly from another.

Comment: where did you find this information? it's true on CI 3 too and maybe 4, but I didn't know it until reading your comment and can't find any info about it!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$this->load->model('decision_model');
$CI =& get_instance();
$CI->decision_model->hello_decision();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also add a `private $_ci;` class variable, and initialize it in your constructor.

```
public function __construct($input=null)
{
    $this->_ci =& get_instance();

    if ( $input != null && is_array($input) ) {
         $this->populate($input);
    }
}
```

Then it'll be available to any function you're working with, no need to `get_instance()` all over the place.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a CodeIgniter Library, and make the library make the model operation and then return it to the current model. I think this approach is more clean.