# how to get value from another model in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i would ask how to get value from another model
so here my code:

```
function savefile($data)
{
    $this->db->insert('master_data', $data);
    $id = $db->insert_id();

}
```

and below model like this :

```
function savefile($data)
{
$data['id'] = //i want get value from above model in $id
$this->db->insert('data_detail', $data);   
}
```

i would ask how to get value id from model in above,cause i create different controllers.

Comment: Please check here .. [Loading and using a codeigniter model from another model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629283/loading-and-using-a-codeigniter-model-from-another-model)

Answer (score 2):

## Controller

```
public function save_file(){
   $data = array(
     'name'=> 'Test'
   );
   $id = $this->model_name->savefile($data);
   $this->model_name1->savefile($data,$id);
}
```

## Model

```
function savefile($data) {
  $this->db->insert('master_data', $data);
  $id = $db->insert_id();
  return $id;
}
```

## Model 2

```
function savefile($data,$id)
{
  $data['id'] = $id;
  $this->db->insert('data_detail', $data);   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Model 1

```
 function savefile($data)
{
    $this->db->insert('master_data', $data);
    return $this->db->insert_id();

}
```

Model 2

```
function savefile($data)
{
$this->load->model('Model1');
$id = $this->Model1->savefile($data); // $id data from model1
$data['id'] = $id;
$this->db->insert('data_detail', $data);   
}
```

hope it's what you looking for