# Call a function of PurchaseModel in to another model name SalesModel without loading PurchaseModel into SalesModel

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-4

Hi Everyone I have a query regarding model of CodeIgniter. I have two model in my project model one is PurchaseModel and model second is SalesModel. In some operation i need a function from PurchaseModel. I can easily copy that function and use it in my SalesModel but i would like to know that "Can I call a function from PurchaseModel to use that function in SalesModel". It will be good if i can get answer in both ways like loading PurchaseModel into SalesModel(if possible) and without loading PurchaseModel to SalesModel.
I am using CodeIgniter-3 version.

Comment: The procedure differs depending on which version of CodeIgniter you're using. Unfortunately, you weren't clear about which version you're referring to.

Comment: CI 3.x : [Loading and using a codeigniter model from another model](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4629544/7376590)

Comment: CI 4.x: [Upgrade Models](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/installation/upgrade_models.html#upgrade-guide)

Comment: CI 4.x :  `$this->x = model('X');`

Comment: I am currently using codeIgniter-3 version

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Loading and using a codeigniter model from another model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629283/loading-and-using-a-codeigniter-model-from-another-model)

Comment: @steven7mwesigwa The above question you mentioned gives me the answer of "with loading model into another model". That means we can't do without loading that model in another model.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Thank You Sir @steven7mwesigwa