# Codeigniter wont let me call model from model , is this true

Tags: php, codeigniter, scope, magic-methods

So I've been trying for hours to get this to work but couldn't!

I have a base model that loads other models. These other models during their construct function reference some variables from the base model. For example:

**User model:**

Check if the user is logged in, and if so, it let's him load his relationships model.

**Relationships model:**

Tries to load the relation of that user during construction. So I tried `$this->user->id`, for example, but it throws an error `" Undefined property "`!

I tried to convert my base model into a library and tried again, but it's not working!

Now this is disappointing and weird! Is there a reason for this? Can we fix it?

I have designed my whole work flow based on this kind of model to call other models and feed data from a third model, etc.

I like to keep my controllers as thin as possible. Is that against CI principles ?

Answer (score 2):

Try below code in your model to access `user` model

```
$CI =& get_instance();
$CI->load->model('user');
// Call new model functions using handle to main CI object
echo $CI->user->id
```

Comment: model is already loaded.. no need to reload it again just to bring it into my scope !.. anyway CI 3 solved this issue. thanks

Answer (score 1):

> **It is possible** and **fully supported** since CodeIgniter v2.XX to call another Model from your current Model.

First, make sure you have the [latest version](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter) of CodeIgniter (or at least v2.01 and above).
            Then, all you need to do is to extend CodeIgniter classes like that:

```
$CI =& get_instance();  (Instead of $CI you can choose any other variable)
```

Now load your Model as you all the time do but this time, instead of using the saved word `$this` that only works directly within your controllers, you'll use the new extended variable `$CI`:

```
$CI->load->model('user');
```

Now, you can call any function within your `user` model and of course, view your `id`:

```
echo $CI->user->id;
```

You can also take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872623/accessing-codeigniter-models-in-other-models) post for more information.

Good Luck!

Answer (score -1):

models/user_model.php

```
class User_model extends CI_Model {

    public $id;

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

models/base_model.php

```
class Base_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->model('user_model');
        //load other models..

        //$this->user is available in your base model
        var_dump( $this->user_model->id );
    }
}
```

controllers/welcome.php

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    public function index() {

        $this->load->model('base_model');

        //$this->user is available in your controller if you load base model
        var_dump( $this->user_model->id );
    }
}
```

About your last question look this one [fat model or fat controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568553/mvc-in-php-fat-model-or-fat-controller)