# How to call the functions of one model class inside another model class?

Tags: codeigniter, model, function-call

I have 2 different model files with one common function.

So I written that function in another model file trying to access that by using:

```
$this->load->model('model_1');
$this->model_1->com_fun();
```

But it is not working. How can I call the functions of one model class inside another model class?

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/872623/accessing-codeigniter-models-in-other-models

Comment: I did it in the same way I loaded the model model_1 within user_model

Comment: what is version of codeigniter ??//

Comment: also check this https://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/132044/#651558

Comment: codeigniter version is 2.1.3

Comment: I'm getting 500 internal server error while making access to another model file..

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes is useful to have in your controllers something like:

```
public function __construct(){

    $this->CI =& get_instance();
}
```

So, when you need another model you can do:

```
$this->CI->load->model('another_codeigniter_model_name', 'another');
$something = $this->CI->another->com_fun();
```